# Assign a task to Task Scheduler from XML File using python :ERROR

Tags: python, windows-task-scheduler

I have an .XML file containing scheduled Task and I would like to add it to the task scheduler via python to a remote server. Is there any way I can do that?

I have tried

```
import os

os.system("schtasks.exe /Create /S 'abc.pggs.com' /RU 'QWERT\DEVenv' /RP 'Passwordin'  /TN  'Hit' /XML 'Hitfiles.xml'")
```

ERROR:

```
Invalid syntax. Mandatory option 'tn' is missing.
Type "CREATE /?" for usage.
'v'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Please add the text of the error as a code instead of adding the screenshot of it.

Comment: edited the question , kindly check @thepunitsingh

Comment: Hi @thepunitsingh , Can you help me in this

Comment: It looks like there is some `v` in your XML file that is not being recognized. Please check for that in the XML, also please paste the content of it or provide a link to it in the question so that we can also check it.

Comment: there is no V in xml document , i double checked it  @thepunitsingh

Comment: Ok. Please copy-paste XML file to the question or provide its link so that we can download and check.

Comment: sorry , i may not be able to send that since it is confidential . But there is no V in XML file @thepunitsingh

Comment: and i think there is something wrong with command @thepunitsingh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226350/discussion-between-thepunitsingh-and-niranjana-neeranj).

Comment: moving to chat..